# What resources are used when bulk emails are sent?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, multithreading, windows-server-2012-r2, bulk-email

I have created a newsletter application in .Net for one of my clients. The database is hosted on a server and application is also hosted on another server.
My question is, when my client will login and create a newsletter (an html file is created). And then send newsletter email to about 50,000 email addresses, what memory resources will be used?

- Local machine
- Database server
- Web Server

P.S. My application loads all email addresses in a server variable and then loop through each value and send's email.

Comment: @CodeCaster I appreciate your comment but your comment doesnt make any sense at all.
My question is simple, I am calling function to send bulk emails to a bulk number of users.
Will the process use server resources or end-user's resources.
Please if you cannot answer a simple question, don't bother adding your comments. Thank you

Comment: My comment got removed, probably because you flagged it, so I don't know what it said. That being said, comments exist to improve questions or explain why questions make no sense, and I think it said something along the lines of: we can't answer this, because we can't see from here how your application works, so we can't say anything relevant about its memory usage. Also, asking about memory usage seems to be the entirely wrong thing to ask when sending emails, it's negligible.

Comment: @CodeCaster Your comment was removed because it wasn't constructive. It starts out -  "You're trying to send a bulk email, and you're concerned with *memory usage*?" - and carries on in the same vein. While this may be true, it doesn't answer the specific question asked. If you don't think the question is useful just down-vote and move on.

Comment: @ChrisF comments don't exist to answer questions. I tried to explain to a question asker why their question made no sense and was unanswerable, hence helping them improve the question. I don't know why that's not considered to be constructive.

Comment: @CodeCaster - it was flagged and I agreed with the flag, If you could have said the same in a more constructive manner I would have probably left the comment alone.

Comment: @ChrisF alright, thanks, I'll try and work on that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create and send 50.000 emails, i think you don't have to worry about memory resources.

But you forgot the most important part, the mail Gateway. This one needs to be configured correctly or otherwise some email providers will treat your mails as spam. To be sure you have to Setup techniques like SPF, DKIM and DMARC.. which is not an easy thing.
Therefore I suggest, you take a look at third party services that are specialized for mass email delivery, than creating the infrastructure on your own. In addition to an easy API, they provide you with Dashboards and lots of useful Information (which emails are delivered/opened/clicked/...)

There are a lot providers, just google for "email delivery Service" and you will find them. They have different pricing models, just see which one fits your needs. Some of them are:

- Sendgrid
- Elasticemail
- Mailgun

Comment: I totally agree wirh you. Building up your own infrastructure is not the right thing.

Comment: Great so getting back to my original question, even if I use third-party provider,
All my data in hosted on a server
My .Net Application calls data from DB 
A multi-thread function, sends emails to all recipients
Will this process take my server resources (any cost)

Comment: No. If your server is not 20 years old, the produced load by sending 50.000 emails is not worth mentioning.